# How to decode this in C#

Tags: c#

i have this in a page source code

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape(escapeall('%$3c%!6f%N62%A6a%H65%#63%]74%L20%P74%T79%]70%F65%A3d%B22%S61%L70%B70%L6c%B69%N63%O61%M74%U69%]6f%-6e%T2f%E78%V2d%Y73%$68%A6f%O63%A6b%@77%J61%L76%J65%M2d%K66%D6c%@61%A73%H68%*22%X20%K63%Q6c%#61%*73%K73%N3d%R22%U70%]6c%?61%T79%B65%!72%-5f%-73%{69%-7a%Y65%Y22%S20%D73%Z74%-79%P6c%N65%D3d%K22%J68%S65%W69%O67%?68%D74%O3a%N33%N30%X34%@70%R78%P22%W20%B64%X61%B74%I61%@3d%+22%A68%.74%T74%X70%$3a%B2f%}2f%T73%C74%@61%@74%R69%?63%Q2e%E61%A6b%U2e%Q66%C62%~63%]64%I6e%C2e%I6e%.65%A74%X2f%F72%I73%M72%B63%?2e%I70%V68%}70%?2f%.7a%K34%N4f%!47%Q35%J2f%K68%*61%V73%@68%Y2f%H37%?71%B6b%V62%B73%K33%I6e%[62%K2e%[73%B77%I66%V22%W3e%A3c%*70%B61%J72%J61%G6d%F20%L6e%Y61%E6d%*65%R3d%A22%B66%X6c%~61%X73%?68%I76%D61%~72%P73%P22%-20%}76%E61%E6c%.75%T65%D3d%A22%.26%O76%U69%-64%{65%N6f%D5f%[73%W72%F63%A3d%V68%[74%$74%Q70%[3a%H2f%A2f%@76%$69%[64%D65%#6f%+2e%W61%C6b%.2e%O66%V61%@63%-65%#62%V6f%+6f%V6b%M2e%Q63%?6f%U6d%W2f%+63%W66%~73%A2d%{61%L6b%Y2d%O61%P73%T68%J32%Y2f%A34%+32%G30%T32%~38%Q2f%C36%$36%X34%U2f%E31%]31%L36%#35%L34%U39%+39%*35%C38%W33%Z39%F37%*32%E38%W34%Y5f%#31%X38%+33%T30%Q32%E2e%+6d%S70%.34%Y26%.76%O69%[64%R65%G6f%~5f%P74%G69%S74%~6c%~65%K3d%!56%-69%[64%D26%K76%.3d%W31%$33%~33%{37%-22%}20%N2f%+3e%K3c%P70%@61%K72%#61%Y6d%V20%~6e%Y61%E6d%A65%{3d%G22%K61%[6c%M6c%$6f%N77%$6e%J65%R74%@77%W6f%M72%*6b%O69%J6e%!67%O22%I20%?76%W61%?6c%T75%!65%B3d%T22%-69%A6e%E74%B65%+72%}6e%L61%~6c%Q22%L20%M2f%!3e%#3c%K70%L61%]72%[61%P6d%F20%G6e%A61%+6d%M65%C3d%V22%J61%Y6c%O6c%U6f%#77%{66%M75%$6c%!6c%N73%J63%Z72%E65%L65%-6e%~22%U20%W76%}61%W6c%$75%K65%Q3d%J22%N74%V72%Y75%T65%]22%A20%~2f%W3e%T3c%@70%V61%D72%R61%H6d%@20%[6e%A61%]6d%~65%T3d%E22%~6d%~6f%T76%P69%N65%}22%}20%S76%Z61%H6c%~75%.65%S3d%K22%L68%M74%E74%G70%+3a%Z2f%?2f%H73%X74%R61%K74%I69%Q63%C2e%}61%E6b%T2e%W66%S62%U63%I64%J6e%#2e%T6e%J65%M74%R2f%]72%Y73%W72%*63%D2e%J70%Z68%+70%~2f%T7a%U34%$4f%.47%U35%J2f%V68%-61%S73%F68%[2f%S37%L71%R6b%V62%I73%U33%E6e%R62%-2e%F73%[77%C66%[22%A20%{2f%U3e%H3c%S2f%S6f%]62%A6a%M65%N63%B74%}3e')));</script>
```

and i want to decode it, in C#, and i don't know how, can somebody help me?

this is it the page source to

```
function escapeall(str){

return str.replace(/([A-Z\~\!\@\#\$\*\{\}\[\]\-\+\.\?\<\>])/g,''); }
```

so this is the code but it's not working

```
string todecode = "%C3c%Q6f%F62%A6a%!65%~63%M74%K20%L74%Y79%J70%#65%N3d%P22%V61%T70%@70%F6c%S69%+63%J61%?74%#69%O6f%@6e%O2f%@78%F2d%{73%.68%H6f%[63%V6b%Y77%D61%$76%Y65%P2d%*66%G6c%Z61%Z73%K68%@22%[20%M63%]6c%T61%A73%#73%-3d%Q22%B70%Y6c%S61%A79%V65%*72%}5f%L73%K69%G7a%K65%G22%?20%M64%K61%L74%@61%[3d%-22%K68%F74%K74%{70%H3a%+2f%G2f%.77%W77%N77%Y2e%Q64%T61%?69%.6c%+79%V6d%*6f%{74%B69%H6f%H6e%E2e%W63%$6f%E6d%O2f%V73%X77%A66%-2f%}76%{69%@64%E65%W6f%*2f%D78%E65%K35%X67%W6a%[72%Q5f%Y67%R69%S61%{6e%I74%$31%V37%T2d%.32%{5f%*73%!68%K6f%[72%F74%I66%K69%{6c%{6d%]73%I22%$3e%S3c%{70%V61%Q72%$61%B6d%!20%?6e%$61%A6d%P65%[3d%B22%]66%G6c%K61%H73%T68%S76%B61%Z72%K73%]22%J20%F76%.61%C6c%+75%H65%+3d%{22%T61%X64%-64%H69%Y74%A69%M6f%@6e%J61%O6c%F49%K6e%J66%R6f%U73%X3d%[30%@22%*20%A2f%P3e%$3c%K70%@61%X72%Z61%-6d%$20%+6e%+61%~6d%N65%R3d%K22%Y61%I6c%E6c%T6f%!77%V6e%I65%[74%U77%R6f%P72%J6b%E69%N6e%#67%+22%I20%X76%P61%F6c%Z75%Y65%S3d%W22%S69%!6e%C74%K65%P72%F6e%Z61%K6c%W22%X20%-2f%.3e%S3c%Q70%R61%-72%U61%Y6d%E20%K6e%O61%B6d%J65%~3d%J22%F61%U6c%Y6c%H6f%E77%.66%F75%I6c%H6c%Z73%A63%}72%}65%J65%H6e%U22%O20%N76%R61%U6c%V75%]65%[3d%O22%E74%K72%Y75%E65%.22%{20%P2f%L3e%H3c%+70%X61%+72%H61%X6d%L20%#6e%P61%]6d%?65%F3d%.22%A6d%$6f%#76%W69%K65%J22%#20%#76%K61%A6c%X75%.65%A3d%R22%$68%O74%?74%D70%T3a%~2f%U2f%@77%U77%H77%F2e%K64%T61%{69%*6c%B79%U6d%O6f%E74%Q69%Q6f%!6e%+2e%Y63%.6f%K6d%[2f%N73%D77%V66%?2f%L76%J69%Q64%.65%*6f%V2f%I78%~65%Y35%E67%Q6a%U72%K5f%U67%R69%I61%T6e%N74%F31%Z37%H2d%M32%~5f%A73%C68%+6f%E72%D74%M66%B69%T6c%C6d%@73%J22%{20%P2f%$3e%W3c%G2f%!6f%L62%X6a%X65%]63%K74%~3e";

        string replaced = Regex.Replace(todecode, @"([A-Z\~!\@#\$*{}[]-+.\?\<>])/g", "");

        string data = Uri.UnescapeDataString(replaced);

        textBoxPrint.Text += data + "";
```

Thanks iande and OneSHOT, now it's working...

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`Uri.UnescapeDataString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) on the string.

It appears that `Uri.Unescpe`, which was my first suggestion, is obsolete, so the static `UnescaptDataString()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got it already.

Every second character in the group is inserted for obfuscation.

```
%$3c%!6f%N62
 ^   ^   ^
```

The following regular expression removes all characters inserted for obfuscation
     replace(/([A-Z\~!\@#\$*{}[]-+.\?\<>])/g,''); }

Once you remove the second character using the above regex you can use answer from @Oded Uri.UnescapeDataString()

The result should be:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="player_size" style="height:304px" data="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z4OG5/hash/7qkbs3nb.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="&video_src=http://video.ak.facebook.com/cfs-ak-ash2/42028/664/116549958397284_18302.mp4&video_title=Vid&v=1337" /><param name="allownetworking" value="internal" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="movie" value="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z4OG5/hash/7qkbs3nb.swf" /></object>
```

Here is the code:

```
        string todecode = "%C3c%Q6f%F62%A6a%!65%~63%M74%K20%L74%Y79%J70%#65%N3d%P22%V61%T70%@70%F6c%S69%+63%J61%?74%#69%O6f%@6e%O2f%@78%F2d%{73%.68%H6f%[63%V6b%Y77%D61%$76%Y65%P2d%*66%G6c%Z61%Z73%K68%@22%[20%M63%]6c%T61%A73%#73%-3d%Q22%B70%Y6c%S61%A79%V65%*72%}5f%L73%K69%G7a%K65%G22%?20%M64%K61%L74%@61%[3d%-22%K68%F74%K74%{70%H3a%+2f%G2f%.77%W77%N77%Y2e%Q64%T61%?69%.6c%+79%V6d%*6f%{74%B69%H6f%H6e%E2e%W63%$6f%E6d%O2f%V73%X77%A66%-2f%}76%{69%@64%E65%W6f%*2f%D78%E65%K35%X67%W6a%[72%Q5f%Y67%R69%S61%{6e%I74%$31%V37%T2d%.32%{5f%*73%!68%K6f%[72%F74%I66%K69%{6c%{6d%]73%I22%$3e%S3c%{70%V61%Q72%$61%B6d%!20%?6e%$61%A6d%P65%[3d%B22%]66%G6c%K61%H73%T68%S76%B61%Z72%K73%]22%J20%F76%.61%C6c%+75%H65%+3d%{22%T61%X64%-64%H69%Y74%A69%M6f%@6e%J61%O6c%F49%K6e%J66%R6f%U73%X3d%[30%@22%*20%A2f%P3e%$3c%K70%@61%X72%Z61%-6d%$20%+6e%+61%~6d%N65%R3d%K22%Y61%I6c%E6c%T6f%!77%V6e%I65%[74%U77%R6f%P72%J6b%E69%N6e%#67%+22%I20%X76%P61%F6c%Z75%Y65%S3d%W22%S69%!6e%C74%K65%P72%F6e%Z61%K6c%W22%X20%-2f%.3e%S3c%Q70%R61%-72%U61%Y6d%E20%K6e%O61%B6d%J65%~3d%J22%F61%U6c%Y6c%H6f%E77%.66%F75%I6c%H6c%Z73%A63%}72%}65%J65%H6e%U22%O20%N76%R61%U6c%V75%]65%[3d%O22%E74%K72%Y75%E65%.22%{20%P2f%L3e%H3c%+70%X61%+72%H61%X6d%L20%#6e%P61%]6d%?65%F3d%.22%A6d%$6f%#76%W69%K65%J22%#20%#76%K61%A6c%X75%.65%A3d%R22%$68%O74%?74%D70%T3a%~2f%U2f%@77%U77%H77%F2e%K64%T61%{69%*6c%B79%U6d%O6f%E74%Q69%Q6f%!6e%+2e%Y63%.6f%K6d%[2f%N73%D77%V66%?2f%L76%J69%Q64%.65%*6f%V2f%I78%~65%Y35%E67%Q6a%U72%K5f%U67%R69%I61%T6e%N74%F31%Z37%H2d%M32%~5f%A73%C68%+6f%E72%D74%M66%B69%T6c%C6d%@73%J22%{20%P2f%$3e%W3c%G2f%!6f%L62%X6a%X65%]63%K74%~3e";
        string replaced = Regex.Replace(todecode, @"([A-Z\~\!\@\#\$\*\{\}\[\]\-\+\.\?\<\>])", "");            
        string data = Uri.UnescapeDataString(replaced);
        textBoxPrint.Text += data + "";
```

But please note that the regex is quite dangerous because it handles this specific case of obfuscation. If you use any uppercase in your hexadecimal encoding the application will crash on the decode.

Comment: Good point on the obfuscation! +1, While i like regex the string seems too hit and miss as in the original post the random chars where all punctuation but then the following string had letters which (i think as i'm no regex expert) the regex seems to miss.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
string todecode = "%C3c%Q6f%F62%A6a%!65%~63%M74%K20%L74%Y79%J70%#65%N3d%P22%V61%T70%@70%F6c%S69%+63%J61%?74%#69%O6f%@6e%O2f%@78%F2d%{73%.68%H6f%[63%V6b%Y77%D61%$76%Y65%P2d%*66%G6c%Z61%Z73%K68%@22%[20%M63%]6c%T61%A73%#73%-3d%Q22%B70%Y6c%S61%A79%V65%*72%}5f%L73%K69%G7a%K65%G22%?20%M64%K61%L74%@61%[3d%-22%K68%F74%K74%{70%H3a%+2f%G2f%.77%W77%N77%Y2e%Q64%T61%?69%.6c%+79%V6d%*6f%{74%B69%H6f%H6e%E2e%W63%$6f%E6d%O2f%V73%X77%A66%-2f%}76%{69%@64%E65%W6f%*2f%D78%E65%K35%X67%W6a%[72%Q5f%Y67%R69%S61%{6e%I74%$31%V37%T2d%.32%{5f%*73%!68%K6f%[72%F74%I66%K69%{6c%{6d%]73%I22%$3e%S3c%{70%V61%Q72%$61%B6d%!20%?6e%$61%A6d%P65%[3d%B22%]66%G6c%K61%H73%T68%S76%B61%Z72%K73%]22%J20%F76%.61%C6c%+75%H65%+3d%{22%T61%X64%-64%H69%Y74%A69%M6f%@6e%J61%O6c%F49%K6e%J66%R6f%U73%X3d%[30%@22%*20%A2f%P3e%$3c%K70%@61%X72%Z61%-6d%$20%+6e%+61%~6d%N65%R3d%K22%Y61%I6c%E6c%T6f%!77%V6e%I65%[74%U77%R6f%P72%J6b%E69%N6e%#67%+22%I20%X76%P61%F6c%Z75%Y65%S3d%W22%S69%!6e%C74%K65%P72%F6e%Z61%K6c%W22%X20%-2f%.3e%S3c%Q70%R61%-72%U61%Y6d%E20%K6e%O61%B6d%J65%~3d%J22%F61%U6c%Y6c%H6f%E77%.66%F75%I6c%H6c%Z73%A63%}72%}65%J65%H6e%U22%O20%N76%R61%U6c%V75%]65%[3d%O22%E74%K72%Y75%E65%.22%{20%P2f%L3e%H3c%+70%X61%+72%H61%X6d%L20%#6e%P61%]6d%?65%F3d%.22%A6d%$6f%#76%W69%K65%J22%#20%#76%K61%A6c%X75%.65%A3d%R22%$68%O74%?74%D70%T3a%~2f%U2f%@77%U77%H77%F2e%K64%T61%{69%*6c%B79%U6d%O6f%E74%Q69%Q6f%!6e%+2e%Y63%.6f%K6d%[2f%N73%D77%V66%?2f%L76%J69%Q64%.65%*6f%V2f%I78%~65%Y35%E67%Q6a%U72%K5f%U67%R69%I61%T6e%N74%F31%Z37%H2d%M32%~5f%A73%C68%+6f%E72%D74%M66%B69%T6c%C6d%@73%J22%{20%P2f%$3e%W3c%G2f%!6f%L62%X6a%X65%]63%K74%~3e";

            StringBuilder replaced = new StringBuilder();

            var i = 0;
            var skipChar = false;
            while (i<todecode.Length)
            {
                if (skipChar)
                    skipChar = false;
                else
                    replaced.Append(todecode.Substring(i, 1));

                skipChar = todecode.Substring(i, 1) == "%";

                i++;
            }

            string data = Uri.UnescapeDataString(replaced.ToString());

            textBoxPrint.Text += data + "";
```

OneSHOT